# Get a Domains Expiration date using Java

Tags: java, sockets

I am working on an application that is suppose to return the expiration date of a Domain name. I used the getExpiration() but it keeps returning 0 for any site that I plug in. EX: www.google.com expires 2020-09-13, but when I run my code it returns 0 meaning it's not known. Does anyone know of any other methods to get the expiration date of a Domain name? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://"+ hostname +":80");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        long date = connection.getExpiration();
        if (date == 0)
          System.out.println("Expiration unknown.");
        else
          System.out.println("Expires: " + new Date(date));
    catch (Exception e)
    {   // ...
    }
```

Comment: From the docs: `Returns the value of the 'expires' header field.` This is an *optional* expiration date one can give on a resource, e.g. a web page or an image, that is associated with the URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "expiration date" for domain names is available through the [Whois](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whois) protocol. Note that not all domain registries expose the domain expiration date, and those that do expose it might do so in different ways.

There may be a Java library that simplifies access to the Whois services; I don't know. Such a thing should be easy to search for.